# Excel Formula to SQL Query Code

Tags: sql, excel, formula

The following formula is used in a column in Excel:

```
=IF(Variable_X(activecell)=Variable_X(cell directly above),IF(AND(Variable_Y(activecell)<>Variable_Y(cell directly above),ActualStartDate(activecell)<>0,FileDate(activecell)>=ActualStartDate(activecell)),1,0),"N")
```

I am really new to SQL and am wondering if this is possible as a SQL query where I would create a new column, and this formula would populate each cell in the column.

Variable_X and Variable_Y are two columns with respective values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a CASE statement in SQL. Something along the lines of:

```
CASE WHEN variablex * activecell = variabley * activecell
AND Variable_Y * activecell != Variable_Y * cell directly above 
AND ActualStartDate * activecell != 0
AND FileDate * activecell >= ActualStartDate * activecell 
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS N
```

A CASE statement can be used almost identically like an IF statement in EXCEL.

Comment: Hi Trent- thanks so much for your help! I will give that a try and play around with how to make it exactly what I need. Thanks for explaining the Case comparison to IF. I use VBA quite a bit so it's nice to understand how they are alike.

Comment: Just a note: `variablex * activecell = variabley * activecell` is the same as `variablex = variabley`.